# Converting date time string to utc

Tags: node.js, utc

I have an input time setting which is like this.

```
{
    "effectiveFrom": "2022-03-24 06:28",
}
```

I need to convert the same to UTC format which is like this

```
{
       "effective_from": "2022-03-24T00:58:00.000Z",
}
```

How can i do that I am using this code over here but this is not working as expected any help is great.

> new Date(ctx.params.dateTime);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The toISOString() method returns a string in
> simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27
> characters long
> (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
> or
> ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ,
> respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix
> "Z".

Source: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
console.log(new Date('2022-03-24 06:28').toISOString())
```

`.toISOString()` will give you the format you are requesting. But you can't perform any date operations on that since the output you get is a string.

I just created a simple node file and check where you are doing wrong.

```
var http = require("http");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize("test", "postgres", "postgres", {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5431,
  dialect: "postgres",
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
  },
});

const UserProfile = sequelize.define("userProfile", {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  DateTimeCol: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
  TimeCol: {
    type: Sequelize.TIME,
  },
});

userProfile.sync().then(() => {
  userProfile.create({
    name: "Test User",
    DateTimeCol: "2022-03-24T08:00:00.000Z",
    TimeCol: "13:00",
  });
  userProfile.findAll().then((data) => console.log("user response", data));
});

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8085);
```

By the way, I have used sequelize and postgres for testing.

Comment: I am getting this now type string is not assignable to type date

Comment: Are you expecting UTC type as Date?
It would be great if you share some of your code related to the types where you actually facing errors.

Comment: I am using this part but i cant change the type here if i does my code breaks in diffrent parts. `@Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
 effective_from: Date;`

Comment: I have added a test code in node where I am reading utc date in string format only. Hope that can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse the date string using `new Date(ctx.params.dateTime)` you will get a [Date object in return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value).

To get the UTC string as output, you can call the [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method on that object.

```js
const dt = new Date('2022-03-24 06:28')

const isoString = dt.toISOString()

console.log(isoString)
```

Comment: I am getting this now type string is not assignable to type date

Comment: @xxoyx Run the code snippet in the answer, it works fine. You must be doing something else in your code. You can share what exactly you're doing there.

Comment: I am using this part but i cant change the type here if i does my code breaks in diffrent parts. `@Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })  effective_from: Date;`